# Why is this statement $\forall x ~ [Smart(x) \vee ~(P(x) \wedge \neg P(x))~]$ satisfiable?

Tags: logic

Why is this statement $$\forall x ~ [Smart(x) \vee ~(P(x) \wedge \neg P(x))~]$$

satisfiable?

Since $\forall x ~ [Smart(x) \vee ~(P(x) \wedge \neg P(x))~]= \forall x ~ Smart(x)$, so shouldn't it be valid because "all x is smart"?

Comment: What do you mean by "satisfiable"?  Just that there exists an interpretation of "$Smart(x)$" and "$P(x)$" for which it is true?

Comment: How did you get rid of the $P(x)$? Sure, one is quickly gone, but not both.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There was a typo, one is $\neg P(x))$

Comment: There is a domain, and an interpretation of smart, in which the sentence is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true in all & only all domains where everything is "Smart". In a  model $(X, S, P)$ where $S$, the interpretation of "Smart", equals $X$, the sentence is true, no matter what $P \subseteq X$ is. There are such models.